# Why does calling datetime hang a thread?

Tags: multithreading, python-3.7, threadpoolexecutor

I am attempting to make use of concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor for the first time. One of my threads (level_monitor) consistently hangs on a call to datetime.now.strftime()—and on another hardware-specific function. For now I am assuming it is the same fundamental problem in both cases.

I've created a reproducible minimum example.

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import socket
from time import sleep

status = 'TRY AGAIN\n'

def get_level():
    print('starting get_level()')
    while True:
        sleep(2)
        now = datetime.now().strftime('%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S')
        print('get_level woken...')

# report status when requested
def serve_level():
    print('starting serve_level()')
    si = socket.socket()
    port = 12345
    si.bind(('127.0.0.1',port))
    si.listen()
    print('socket is listening')
    while True:
        ci, addr = si.accept()
        print('accepted client connection from ',addr)
        with ci:
            req = ci.recv(1024)
            print( req )
            str = status.encode('utf-8')
            ci.send(str)
            ci.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    nthreads = 5
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(nthreads) as executor:
        level_monitor = executor.submit(get_level)
        server = executor.submit(serve_level)
```

When I run it I see the serve_level thread works fine. I can talk to that thread using telnet. I can see the level_monitor thread starts too, but then it hangs before print('get_level woken...'). If I comment out the call to datetime then the thread behaves as expected.

I am sure that when I find out why I will have found out a lot.

Comment: in main, just run `get_level` (without threading) to see the problem

Comment: Excellent suggestion. That revealed I'd omitted `from datetime import datetime`.

Comment: friendly suggestion: if you follow the steps to create a minimal reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), you'll be able to discover problems like this before you post the question (and if you don't, it will make it easier for us to help)